# Newsletter sign up on footer showing white text on Macs

Tags: wordpress, footer, newsletter

I'm getting reports of when someone types in their info into the newsletter sign up in the footer on this site: https://www.hawaiianmanagement.com/ that the text is invisible or white. I'm wondering if anyone knows how I can make it black or if it's just a MAC issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go; enjoy.

```
#mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group input {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-indent: 2%;
    color: #000000; // add this
}
```